# Listen for MSTeams channel (configuration) tab config changes

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I have a channel (*configuration*) tab with a config page & using the Teams JS SDK v2. Within my tab, I want to react if the user modifies the settings in the tab, for instance, if the `entityId`/ `page.id`) changes.

The handler `microsoftTeams.pages.config.registerChangeConfigHandler(() => {});` says that's what it does... it's raised went the tab's configuration changes, but when I implement it, the settings page never loads and no errors appear in the console. If I remove it, the settings page appears.

```
// in channel tab
microsoftTeams.pages.config.registerChangeConfigHandler(() => {
  console.log('tab.config changed => ', context.page);
});
```

Since the handler takes no arguments, can't determine if there's a way to tell it to show the settings page.

Ideas? Trying to avoid using something like a `setTimeout()` within the tab to periodically check if a value changed

Comment: `registerChangeConfigHandler` method is used to register a handler for when the user attempts to update the tab configuration, not when the configuration has already been changed. This method is called when the user clicks on the "Settings" option for the tab. This method should be used to validate the settings and call the setConfig method to update the tab configuration.

Comment: OK, so that method wasn't what I was looking for. Thanks for explaining it.

Is it possible for the tab to determine when the settings page is closed? I'm not seeing the tab refresh once the settings/config page has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

When the user changes the settings (e.g. clicks the "Save") button, Teams will reload your actual main app tab -in any case-. As a result, if you're reading something from the querystring or context, or saving (on the config tab) to a DB and reading (in your main tab), you'll get the updated config changes in any case. As a result, you might not actually need to "listen" for changes in the way you're thinking in case. Maybe that helps?

Comment: "Teams will reload the actual main app tab" - I'm not seeing that. that's why I'm trying to find an event to attach to.I've setup listeners to log when the tab is loaded and none of them fire when the settings page is closed or when I click the "save" button.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I presume you're doing all the correct stuff in your config page:
`await microsoftTeams.app.initialize();`, `microsoftTeams.pages.config.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent) => {` ... `saveEvent.notifySuccess()`, that kind of stuff?

Comment: I'm referencing per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page?tabs=teamsjs-v2#example

Comment: Yes... although I'm using the teamsfx-react package's "useTeams()" hook which calls initialize() for me. The tab shows it's id (`page.id` / `entityId`), opens a settings page, which saves the config which changes the `entityId` and closes the settings just fine. If I navigate off & back to the tab, I see the value that was saved in the settings, but the tab itself isn't refreshed when the settings page closes. 

The page you reference is only for the settings page... there's nothing wrong there & works as expected, it's the TAB that's not refreshing.

Comment: The crux of my problem: everything works EXCEPT the tab isn't refreshing automatically when it's configuration changes. So I'm trying to find another way (without using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`) to update a React state value on the tab when it's `entityId` changes

Comment: Yeah, I'm only showing the settings page, as you said, but in my testing, setting the notifySuccess on the config page (the mini iframe that Teams shows) *is* reloading the main window - strange that it's not doing the same for you.

Comment: oh, I figured out why you're seeing this - it was my silly testing. When I looked at this originally, it was with a test tenant, so I was just testing in browser. *There*, Teams reloads the tab. In Desktop it doesn't seem to do that. Playing around a bit more my side in case something turns up.

Comment: Wierd. I tried now to sign in to Desktop with my test account, and it's working fine - refreshing the underneath tab when I click Save on the Config page. This is the same code!

Comment: Interesting... I never tried desktop as I only do dev with the web client, never the desktop clients until the end. For me, browser never reloads the tab.

Comment: ICYRC, I logged the issue to the TeamsFX repo and included a link to a video showing the issue. Definitely something odd...  https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/10077